# How to set authorization header like Bearer token in cron job?

Tags: postgresql, authorization, plpgsql, http-get, supabase

I am just trying to write a cron job using postgres.

For a simple http get I am able to get it work but not quite sure how to handle a get request with authorization header
here is an example of http get without authorization header

```
select
  cron.schedule(
    'webhook-every-minutex', -- name of the cron job
    '* * * * *', -- every minute
    $$
    select content::json->'results'
from http_get('https://swapi.dev/api/people');
    $$
  );
```

How can we add authorization header like Bearer token to the above code?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this the package you are using?  https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http#:~:text=Run%20a%20GET%20request%20with%20an%20Authorization%20header.  BTW, that is really interesting and the first I've ever heard of this extension, so thank you for that.

Comment: I am using Supabase to take care of db which is backed by postgres, they recommend us to write in such way for handling cron jobs.

Comment: That link in my last comment has an example of how to set an authentication JWT token.  It looks like you need to use `http()` instead of `http_get` to do it, though.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same boat. Supabase's example doesnt give a simple "how to make a post request, or get request that requires an authorization header". Like Mike O. said in the comment you need to use the http function. I'll give an example in hopes that it helps someone who comes after me.

```
begin
 return(
   select "content"::jsonb
   from http(
     ('GET','http://xxx/indexes/movies/search', 
      ARRAY[http_header('Authorization', 'Bearer {mytoken}')],
      'application/json',
      '{"q":"body"}'
     )::http_request
    )
 );
 end;
```

Couple of things to be mindful of.

1. the function isn't just http(...) but rather http((..)) --- (that double parentheses threw me off at the start)
2. even though in the http_post() or http_get() the content type is the last parameter. The http() function has the content-type before the body. ---(this suprisingly was a night nightmare and shamefully took a while to realize)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Try this:

```
select
  cron.schedule (
    'webhook-every-minutex',
    '* * * * *', -- every minute
    $$
    select 
      http(
          ('GET','https://swapi.dev/api/people', 
            ARRAY[http_header('Authorization', 'Bearer {Place token here}')],
            'application/json',
            '{}'
          )::http_request
          )
    $$
  );
```